# MongoDB: How To Delete All Records Of A Collection in MongoDB Shell?

Tags: mongodb

I've tried

```
db.users.remove(*)
```

Although it returns an error so how do I go about clearing all records?

Comment: db.getCollection('collectionname').remove({})

Comment: Please do not intentionally break the very simple UX design of this Q&A by posting resolving advice as a comment under the question.  All resolving insights should be posted as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

The argument to `remove()` is a filter document, so passing in an empty document means 'remove all':

```
db.user.remove({})
```

However, if you definitely want to remove everything you *might* be better off dropping the collection. Though that probably depends on whether you have user defined indexes on the collection i.e. whether the cost of preparing the collection after dropping it outweighs the longer duration of the `remove()` call vs the `drop()` call.

More details [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/).

Comment: `remove` is now deprecated. use `db.user.deleteMany({})` instead

Comment: @MahdiehShavandi looking at the Mongo shell docs I can't see anything saying that `remove` is deprecated (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/). Can you provide a link or a citation in support of that claim?

Comment: sorry, I'd better say: it's going to be deprecated in the future versions. It just logs this claim in the terminal.

Comment: DeprecationWarning: Collection.remove() is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, findOneAndDelete, or bulkWrite.

Comment: What about db.user.delete_all?

Answer (score 64):

You can delete all the documents from a collection in MongoDB, you can use the following:

```
db.users.remove({})
```

Alternatively, you could use the following method as well:

```
db.users.deleteMany({})
```

Follow the following MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/remove-documents/#delete-all-documents), for further details.

> To remove all documents from a collection, pass an empty filter document `{}` to either the `db.collection.deleteMany()` or the `db.collection.remove()` method.

Comment: `remove()` [prints a warning that its deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368368/mongodb-how-to-delete-all-records-of-a-collection-in-mongodb-shell#comment113856243_46368397)

Answer (score 29):

Here is the command to delete all the records of a collection in the **MongoDB shell** or **MongoDB Compass shell** (**_MongoSH**).

```
show dbs                                    -> to list all the database
use test-database                           -> to select the database
db.getCollection('orders').deleteMany({})   -> to select the collection and deletes all the data.
```

Or

```
show dbs                     -> to list all the database
use test-database            -> to select the database
db.orders.remove({})      -> to select the collection and deletes all the data.
```

Answer (score 20):

Use the `deleteMany` function ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/)):

Assuming your collection named `users`:

```
db.users.deleteMany({})
```

`deleteMany` takes a *filter* as argument, and passing the *empty document* `{}`  as the filter is equivalent to asking that all members of the collection be deleted.

Note that `remove` should still work, but you'll need to pass the same empty document:

```
db.users.remove({})
```

However, `remove` has been deprecated, and if your mongo install is up to date, using `remove` should lead to a deprecation warning indicating that you should instead use one of the preferred methods. From 1.0.7:

> DeprecationWarning: Collection.remove() is deprecated. Use deleteOne,
> deleteMany, findOneAndDelete, or bulkWrite.

Answer (score 10):

```
db.users.count()
db.users.remove({})
db.users.count()
```

Answer (score 9):

Delete all documents from a collection in cmd:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin
mongo
use yourdb
db.yourcollection.remove( { } )
```

This example is made for MongoDB 4.2

Answer (score 7):

To remove all the documents in all the collections:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach( function(collection_name) { 
    if (collection_name.indexOf("system.") == -1) {
        print ( ["Removing: ", db[collection_name].count({}), " documents from ", collection_name].join('') );
        db[collection_name].remove({}); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code to remove all documents from all collections except starting from "system.".

```
use('DatabaseName');
db.getCollectionNames()
  .filter((collectionName) => collectionName.indexOf("system.") === -1)
  .forEach((collectionName) => {
    print(`Removing: ${db[collectionName].count({})} documents from ${collectionName}`);
    db[collectionName].deleteMany({});
  });
```

This code can be run in the MongoDB playground as well.
It will also print the number of documents deleted per collection.